# Material-UI Capitalize words in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to capitalize the text within a `<TextField>` component.

Current text: LeaGUE oF lEGENdS 
Desired format: League Of Legends

I've tried to use `text-transform: 'capitalize'` but it's not working how I expect it to.

I also have a function that will capitalize my text using plain JS:

```
string.toLowerCase()
            .split(' ')
            .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
            .join(' ');
```

The problem is that I don't know how I should use the JS function because I want to capitalize text in multiple `<TextField>` components, but I don't want to override material-ui components. Is there a way to use the props?

Comment: If you override a material-ui component you dont have to override all textfields, you can do it for a single one using the classes property. https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/, so i don't really see a problem with that.

Comment: @TimvonKänel first of all thank you for you answer. Ok, I understant your point. But how can I use classes property to have the wanted result. Because using a class with style text-transform: 'capitalize' as I said it's not working.

Comment: @gequotiseerde did you ever figure this out? I want to do the same thing but make it all Upper Case and cant seem to figure it out

Answer (score 16):

An easy way to transform "LeaGUE oF lEGENdS" into "League Of Legends" is to make use of the inputProps prop:

`<TextField inputProps={{style: {textTransform: 'capitalize'}}} />`

Answer (score 6):

I don't see it in the `material-ui` docs but `material-ui/core` looks to have a capitalize utility function. So...

```
import { capitalize } from '@material-ui/core';

...

const text = 'something';

console.log(capitalize(text)); // 'Something'
```

Comment: The material-ui version I am using(5.10.8), capitalize moved into `@mui/material/utils`

Answer (score 4):

In css, you could have used text-transform. In **material-ui**, you can do this way:

**1.** If you want all letters to be in caps-

```
<TextField inputProps={{style: {**textTransform**: 'uppercase'}}} />
```

Example: hello => HELLO

**2.** If you want only first letter to be in caps-

```
<TextField inputProps={{style: {**textTransform**: 'capitalize'}}} />
```

Example: hello => Hello

**3.** If you want all letters to be in lowercase-

```
<TextField inputProps={{style: {**textTransform**: 'lowercase'}}} />
```

Example: HEllo => hello

Comment: What's your question??

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to rewrite another solution to a problem that other people have solved many times before. You can use [`lodash.startcase`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.startcase) package to do just that.

```
npm i lodash.startcase
```

### Usage

```js
import startcase from 'lodash.startcase';

const capitalizeWord = (value) => startCase(value.toLowerCase())

capitalizeWord('--foo-bar--');
// => 'Foo Bar'
 
capitalizeWord('fooBar');
// => 'Foo Bar'
 
capitalizeWord('__FOO_BAR__');
// => 'Foo Bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I dont't think you can do this using only css, you need some javacsript.

Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-s5us4

or

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";

class CustomTextField extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  onChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ value: this.prettyString(value) });
  };

  prettyString = str => {
    var nextCapital = true;
    var newString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      var cur = str.charAt(i);
      if (nextCapital) {
        newString += cur.toUpperCase();
      } else {
        newString += cur.toLowerCase();
      }
      if (cur === " ") {
        nextCapital = true;
      } else {
        nextCapital = false;
      }
    }
    return newString;
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return <TextField value={value} onChange={this.onChange} />;
  }
}

render(<CustomTextField />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Comment: if I'm typing LEAGUE OF LEGENDS all letters are uppercase..but the input should be forced to use the rule and the result to be: League Of Legends

Comment: Yes you can do it with CSS: text-transform: capitalize; https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Answer (score 0):

This will take LeaGUE oF lEGENdS and give you League of legends if that helps.

```js
function App(props) {
    const classes = props.classes;
    return (
        <div className="App">
                <TextField label={'LeaGUE oF lEGENdS '} className={classes.classOne}/>
        </div>
    );
}

const styles = theme =>
    createStyles({
    classOne: {
        textTransform: 'lowercase',
        '& > :first-letter': {
            textTransform: 'capitalize'
        }
    }

});
```

I didn't realize you wanted to dynamically affect the value, my code for this :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

function App(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(
      e.target.value
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .map(word => {
          return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
        })
        .join(" ")
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```